# Getting "1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind" installing DSE OpsCenter on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, opscenter

I am trying to install DSE Opscenter on Kubernetes.

Below is my cluster file

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ops-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
reclaimPolicy: Retain
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-storage-0
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  claimRef:
    name: config-clusters-volume-opscenter-0
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  storageClassName: ops-storage
  local:
    path: /data/k8s-data/cassandra-0
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - ubuntuserver
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: opscenter-ext-lb
  labels:
    app: opscenter
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8888
    name: opsc-gui-port
  - port: 8443
    name: opsc-secure-port
  selector:
    app: opscenter
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: opscenter
  labels:
    app: opscenter
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8888
    name: opsc-gui-port
  - port: 8443
    name: opsc-secure-port
  - port: 61620
    name: port-61620
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: opscenter
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: opscenter
spec:
  serviceName: "opscenter"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: opscenter
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: opscenter
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: opscenter
          image: gcr.io/datastax-public/dse-opscenter:6.5.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["/update_admin_password.sh"]
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "2"
              memory: "4000Mi"
          env:
          - name: DS_LICENSE
            value: accept
          - name: OPSC_ADMIN_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: opsc
                key: admin_password 
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8888
            name: opsc-gui-port
          - containerPort: 61620
            name: port-61620
          volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /config
          - name: config-clusters-volume
            mountPath: /opt/opscenter/conf/clusters
          - name: ssl-store-volume
            mountPath: /var/lib/opscenter/ssl
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: opsc-config
      - name: ssl-store-volume
        configMap:
          name: opsc-ssl-config
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
                operator: In
                values:
                - ubuntuserver
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: config-clusters-volume
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: ops-storage
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

But I get the below error when I try to do so, I get the below error while listing the pods.

**0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.**

I tried several ways but neither of them worked. Can someone please help me with this.

Any tutorial or link that shows how to install DSE Opscenter on Kubernetes would be helpful too.

Please note: I need to use local storage for the above.

Comment: Can you check the PV status? Maybe with a `k get pv local-storage-0 -oyaml` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've installed DSE using the cass-operator, OpsCenter is not designed to be installed on a Kubernetes cluster and it's not a supported configuration. It will definitely not work.

The recommendation is to use open-source tools like https://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra to monitor your cluster instead of OpsCenter.

For the same reason, [K8ssandra.io](https://dtsx.io/3znMa05) has all these tools already bundled in and pre-configured when you launch Cassandra on Kubernetes:

- [Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/docs/) for automated repairs
- [Medusa](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-medusa/wiki) for backups and restores
- [Metrics Collector](https://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra) for monitoring with Prometheus + Grafana
- Traefik templates for k8s cluster ingress
- [Stargate.io](https://dtsx.io/2XHbiRo) - a data gateway for connecting to Cassandra using REST API, GraphQL API and JSON/Doc API

K8ssandra uses the same cass-operator under the hood. Cheers!